# Converting XML tag to java config

Tags: spring, annotations, spring-batch, batch-processing

I want to transform the XML tag of this spring batch job to java based annotation but it seems that i can't find the **handler** property in java config

XML config

```
 <job id="partitionJob" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">

    <step id="masterStep">
    <partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
        <handler grid-size="10" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
    </partition>
    </step>

  </job>
```

Java config

```
@Bean
public Step masterStep() throws Exception {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("exportStep")
            .partitioner(slave().getName(), rangePartitioner())
            .step(slave()())
            .gridSize(10)
            .taskExecutor(taskExecutor())
            .build();
}



    @Bean
    public Job partitionJob() throws Exception {

        return jobBuilderFactory.get("partitionJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(masterStep())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not confident with JavaConfig but seems grid-size and task-executor properties are mapped by gridSize() and taskExecutor() methods.

Comment: Yes i pass those to the Master step but can't pass them to the partitionner

Comment: And i don't see any performance while using local partitioning

Comment: As Luca mentioned, in your case, you don't need to provide a handler, we've done it for you via the grid size, etc.

Comment: Thanks for response but i'm confused about PartitionHandler interface

http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/partition/PartitionHandler.html